# Xamarin.Android Layout Designer not loading

Tags: android, xamarin, layout, designer

I am working in VS2017. The layout designer will load after the application has loaded but if I make a change to the layout and navigate away, more frequently than not, when I return to the layout, the designer will be stuck loading and the 'Source' tab is disabled. I have checked the layout file and the axml is correct.

If I close VS2017 and open it up, I can see my layout in the designer but the problem recurs. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Searching returns results from 2016 for VS2015. I might have overlooked other questions. I apologize ahead of time.

Comment: No errors and the designer just stuck?

Comment: No errors. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/Ph10Q) is what it looks like.

Comment: Have you updated VS to the last?